# Firefox date format in dev console

Tags: date, console

In the dev console on Firefox I go to Test, New Run and select my Test Class to run.  I'm in UK and today is 9th April (9/4 in UK).  The test gets enqueued for 4th September - 9/4 US style!

If I do the same in Chrome it is enqueued for today.  But I'd rather use Firefox!

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Have you checked Firefox for updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language of Mozilla firefox then it may show you the write time.
here it the link that may help you.

http://hr.anu.edu.au/__documents/about-hr/hr-systems/horus-resources/how_to_change_date_format_using_mozilla_firefox.pdf

Comment: I followed the doc and the language setting was ok as it was.  I have now realised that it is just a display thing, even though the test shows as enqueued on the wrong date it does run now (ish).  I'll live with it!